# Can't save number with a comma ( , )

Tags: c#

I get an error says `3,400.00 is not a valid value for Decimal.`

**SQL DataType**

`decimal(18, 2)`

**Code**

```
 public ActionResult _UpdatePrograms(String trainings, int id){
   JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   string[] sep = new string[] { "|" };
   String[] ec;
   ec = trainings.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
   Program training = jss.Deserialize<Program>((string)ec[0]);  //-- In this I got an error like I said above
 }
```

How can I save the value above input from the user?. If I remove the comma `( , )`, theres no problem on saving the data.

Comment: @Xufox - it's not a java program. :)

Comment: @Xufox I add the JS tag maybe there is a way in JS Side.

Comment: Why not just replace the comma with a blank? `yourString.Replace(",","")`

Comment: @sorifiend great idea.. I totally forgot about the replace function.. Make it as an answer.. I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [String.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) method to achieve what you want.

For example you could do this to remove the `,`:

```
ec[0] = ec[0].Replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

try parsing the "3,400.00" to decimal.

example:

```
string testString = "3,400.00";
decimal x = decimal.Parse(testString);
```

Comment: While my answer does work, this is the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a parse with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, which uses a dot `.` for decimal point, and comma `,` for group separation:

```
decimal dec = decimal.Parse("1,200,800.05", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Note:** Passing `CultureInfo` ensures that `Parse` treats comma and dot consistently with the format that you used in the question. As its name suggests, it remains invariant on computers with a different culture setting, e.g. European, where comma is used as a decimal point.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/HaswJp)